# Why does setting the DataContext of a Window to {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} allow you to databind to the properties of code-behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

According to my understanding, setting the `DataContext` to a control itself will allow you to access the property of that control using data binding without specifying the `Source`, so setting the `DataContext` of a `Window` to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` should only allow you to data bind to the properties defined in the `Window` class, not the ones in the code-behind because the code-behind file only inherited the `Window` class, and the properties I defined in the code-behind file don't directly belong to the `Window` class. However, when I do it, it magically allows me to data bind to the properties I defined in the code-behind file. How does this work?

Comment: See those words "partial class"  in the code behind? Code behind and the xaml are the same class. Which is why you can access controls in the window using this. In code behind.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, I reworded my question. What I was asking was why am I allowed to data bind to the properties defined in the code-behind when all I am declaring in the XAML is a `Window`, not the class I have in the code-behind. How does the XAML parser know that I want to bind to those properties? Even though my code-behind class extends `Window`, my understanding is that the XAML parser only knows about its own `Window` class and not the one I extended from it. Maybe it's the `x:Class` that did the magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting the `DataContext` of a control to itself allows you to access its properties in a `Binding`.

- Code-Behind

  ```
  public MyWindow()
  {
     DataContext = this;
     InitializeComponent();
  }
  ```

  Creating a `Binding` in XAML will automatically [inherit this `DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) as `Source` for binding if it is not overridden e.g. an item is set as `DataContext` in an `ItemsControl`.

  > Data context is a concept that allows elements to inherit information from their parent elements about the data source that is used for binding, as well as other characteristics of the binding, such as the path. [...]
- XAML

  ```
  <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          x:Class="MyWpfApp.MyWindow"
       ...
          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  ```

  The [`RelativeSource` will set the `Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the `Binding` to the window itself. The same would be true, if you would use `AncestorType={x:Type Window}`.

  > Gets or sets the binding source by specifying its location relative to the position of the binding target.

  You [cannot set multiple different sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/binding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-properties-that-can-be-set-with-the-binding-extension) on a single binding.

  > `RelativeSource`: mutually exclusive versus with `ElementName` and `Source`;

In essence, the you never bind without setting a `Source`, it is set implicitly or explicitly.

---

Why does the `Binding` work then, if you specify a `Window` as source? You have to understand, that the XAML file and your code-behind are one and the same class after compilation. They are both `partial` definitions that are merged on compilation. You are right that you inherit from `Window`, but your understanding of bindings is wrong. If we talk about class inheritance, you are right, accessing a derived `MyWindow` through a `Window` reference would not allow you to access its properties, but bindings do not work this way. They are **expressions** that **loosley couple** dependency properties to properties being bound. They are only [resolved at run-time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/binding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which means they are applied to the actual **run-time type** of the `DataContext`, which is `MyWindow`.

> Defers a property value to be a data-bound value, creating an **intermediate expression object** and interpreting the **data context that applies** to the element and its binding **at run time**.

You could assign and switch any arbitrary `object` as `DataContext` even of different types. As long as the `Path` of any binding matches any property value it will be resolved successfully, otherwise there will be a binding error.

Comment: Does that mean even though I am declaring a `Window` in the XAML, the type being instantiated at run time is actually `MyWindow`? If so, does this happen to other controls as well? i.e. controls that will have a different type than declared in the XAML

Comment: @palapapa Do not confuse yout XAML file definition for your window with the binding that resolves a value, those are completely different things. The type is already `MyWindow` at **compile time**, since you create a new type `MyWindow` that derives from `Window`. This is inheritance. The [`x:Class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xclass-directive) attribute connects the XAML markup with the code-behind file, but in the end this is one and the same class, the one derived from `Window`. This is true for other types, e.g. defining a custom `UserControl` as well.